# Save a function definition in ipython

Tags: python, macros, ipython

When using ipython I often want to save specific functions I have defined during my session, e.g.:

```
In [1]: def func1():
...:        pass
...: 

In [2]: %save func1.py func1
func1 is neither a string nor a macro.
```

Instead I have to pick out the function definition line number from `enumerate(_ih)`, or manually copy and paste from vim if I have `%edit`'d the function.

Is there a way to achieve `%save func1.py func1`? I feel like it should be possible as ipython has access to the definition when using %edit.

**Edit**

Line based saving doesn't work if I have at some point edited the function with `%ed`. I'm looking for a way to save the *new* function definition in this case.

Comment: We could add the ability to save functions and classes, I imagine. The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L2738). Have a chat with us on the ipython mailing list if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll look into submitting a patch.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can save the contents of line `1` with `%save` using:

```
In [2]: %save func1.py 1
The following commands were written to file `func1.py`:
def func1():
    pass
```

Help on `%save` is available with:

```
In [2]: %save?
Type:       Magic function
...
Docstring:
Save a set of lines or a macro to a given filename.

Usage:
  %save [options] filename n1-n2 n3-n4 ... n5 .. n6 ...
```

You can `%edit` a function body with:

```
In [3] %edit func1
 done. Executing edited code...
```

After `%edit`-ing your function `func1`, you can get the following output from IPython using `_`:

```
In [4]: _
Out[4]: 'def func1():\n    print "Hello World"\n\n'
```

Then, you can define or re-define a `%macro` with the update `func1` contents like this:

```
In [5]: %macro new_func1_macro _
Macro `new_func1_macro` created. To execute, type its name (without quotes).
=== Macro contents: ===
def func1():
    print "Hello World"
```

Finally, you can save the new version of `func1` with `%save` and the new `%macro` like this:

```
In [6]: %save func1.py new_func1_macro
The following commands were written to file `func1.py`:
def func1():
    print "Hello World"
```

Hope that clarifies.

Comment: This is how I've been using it. However this raises a problem if I then edit the function with %ed in the interim. I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Clarified my answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

```
 In [1]: def a():
   ...:     print('hello')
   ...:     return

In [2]: from inspect import getsource

In [3]: %save a.py getsource(a)

The following commands were written to file `a.py`:
def a():
    print('hello')
    return
```

Comment: While I love the style here, and the use of builtins, apparently this does not work if the def has already been altered in iPython via %edit.

Answer (score 0):

For me the easiest way from ipython is to call:

```
%edit foo
```

Then in vim do:

```
:saveas directory/name.py
:x
```

This way you get a copy for yourself.  If you want to dump it into a specific file use vim's

```
:read directory/file
```

to import the contents.